# SPARK Dataframes : Filter DF1 if a column value exist in another dataframe DF2

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark-sql

I have 2 spark dataframes DF1 and DF2. I have to select from DF1 where DF1.NUMBER exits in DF2.NUMBER

[image]

Desired Output as below

[image]

Requesting Help

Answer (score 1):

You can use inner join

Here is an example using Scala Spark API

Create dataframes:

```scala
val df1 = Seq(
    (100, "Alex"),
    (101, "Thomas"),
    (102, "Susan"),
    (103, "Jermy"),
    (104, "Silva"),
    (105, "Lee")
).toDF("Number", "Name")

val df2 = Seq(100, 105).toDF("Number")

df1.show(false)

df2.show(false)

Output:
+------+------+
|Number|Name  |
+------+------+
|100   |Alex  |
|101   |Thomas|
|102   |Susan |
|103   |Jermy |
|104   |Silva |
|105   |Lee   |
+------+------+

+------+
|Number|
+------+
|100   |
|105   |
+------+
```

Join:

```scala
df1
        .join(df2, Seq("Number"), "inner")
        .show(false)

Output:
+------+----+
|Number|Name|
+------+----+
|100   |Alex|
|105   |Lee |
+------+----+
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply .  Now getting below error - name 'Seq' is not defined

Comment: @Avi what language do you use? Scala, python or SQL?